# Change language for user in Django

Tags: python, django

At https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/ it is mentioned that I can change the language of the page.

However, the link explains how to do this for the user's current session. I want to change the language for the authorized user.

I want to change it within a settings view by something like

```
class UserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    fields = ['language']

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve.
1) Do you want to change language for user's session?
2) Do you want to change it globally or for a selected page?

Comment: I want to change language for user's session. But the language selection should be the same next time the user login even though he/she has closed his browser in the meantime (and hence deleting the previous session)

Comment: Have you added the language field to the User model?

Comment: Yes I have. It's just a CharField: `language = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("language"), max_length=10, choices=settings.LANGUAGES, default=settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)`